# Unable to run dtsx package

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

Error is thrown "To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install SSIS log provider for SQL Server of Integration Services or higher."
When I am trying to run package from Excute package utility of SQL Integration services I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, the problem was that I haven't got some SQL features installed. Since I had express edition of server itself and tried to install integration services from developers package.